# security of REST api - token invalidation

Tags: api, rest, json-web-token

I have a REST api that serves multiple customers. Today, each customer gets its own api key that is sent in the headers of each request. The api key is an encrypted string that contains data about the customer, his permissions etc. The key that decrypts the api keys is the same for all customers, and it is stored in the server. If a customer leaves us, I want to be able to invalidate his token, without invalidating the tokens of the rest of the clients. That creates a problem. I can, for example, store each customer's token in the customers table, but then each request to the api will require me to run a query against the customers table, which may slow things down. It is also possible to store the tokens in a json file, which may be faster, but I don't know. What do you think is the best solution? BTW, thanks but I'm not interested in OAuth.

Comment: Database is internally a file storage isn't it ? You may very well store all valid keys in a flat file or JSON file and write a filter that can intercept all requests and validate token from this file before proceeding further. This will be filter with highest precedence.

Comment: yes, but is a json file faster than a database? and is there a way to avoid using a data storage at all in this case?and what about concurrency? I'm using node js behind an apache proxy.

Comment: If you want it simple, read the JSON file during start up and create an in-memory map. You will have to restart the application whenever you change the file. Or you can have admin URL which will trigger updating the in-memory map. You may also consider similar options with EhCache and database and expose an admin URL through which you can invalidate the Cache. Since this is a read-only operation, there should not be any concurrency issues.

Comment: If you are adding, updating or deleting records to database through the application ONLY, then it is fairly easy to invalidate cache in those operations. No need of exposing a separate URL also, but it is handy for customer support.